# Is Encoding the same as Escaping?

Tags: encoding, escaping, theory

I am interested in theory on whether Encoding is the same as Escaping? According to Wikipedia

> an escape character is a character
>   which invokes an alternative
>   interpretation on subsequent
>   characters in a character sequence.

My current thought is that they are different. Escaping is when you place an escape charater in front of a metacharacter(s) to mark it/them as to behave differently than what they would have normally.

Encoding, on the other hand, is all about transforming data into another form, and upon wanting to read the original content it is decoded back to its original form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're different, and I think you're getting the distinction correctly.

Encoding is when you transform between a logical representation of a text ("logical string", e.g. Unicode) into a well-defined sequence of binary digits ("physical string", e.g. ASCII, UTF-8, UTF-16). Escaping is a special character (typically the backslash: '\') which initiates a different interpretation of the character(s) following the escape character; escaping is necessary when you need to encode a larger number of symbols to a smaller number of distinct (and finite) bit sequences.

Answer (score 12):

Escaping is a subset of encoding: You only encode certain characters by prefixing a special character instead of transferring (typically all or many) characters to another representation.

Escaping examples:

- In an SQL statement: ... WHERE name='O\' Reilly'
- In the shell: `ls Thirty\ Seconds\ *`
- Many programming languages: `"\"Test\"` string (or `"""Test"""`)

Encoding examples:

- Replacing `<` with `&lt;` when outputting user input in HTML
- The character encoding, like UTF-8
- Using sequences that do not include the desired character, like `\u0061` for `a`

Comment: Hmm, could you elaborate more? I don't think Encoding requires you to encode all characters; for example, HTML encoding encodes only parts of the content.

Comment: Clarified, my previous definition was indeed imprecise.

Answer (score 1):

They are indeed different.

You pretty much got it right.

Comment: Then why does the JS function "escape" transform data into another form and then you have to "unescape" it to get the original content? Seems more like the definition of encoding in this question